# Cannot invoke index with an argument list of type '(of: Any)'

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data, swift3

I am making a news app where you can select topics that you want to see. The problem I am having is where you deselect the topic. All of the selected topics are added to CoreData in an Entity called `ArticleSource` under the Attribute of `source`. The error occurs when I try to locate the topic in the array called `Results` using the string `title`. As I dont know the position of the topic in the array I try to locate it using `index(of: )` method which produces the error: `Cannot invoke index with an argument list of type '(of: Any)'`

Any help appreciated.

```
do {

            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
            let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "ArticleSource")
            request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

            var results = try context.fetch(request)
            if results.count > 0 {

                for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {
                    if let source = result.value(forKey: "source") as? String {
                        if source == title {
                            print("it matches")

                            if let index = results.index(of: title) {
                                results.remove(at: index)
                            }
                        }

                        print("results = \(results)")
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }

        do {
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
            try context.save()
            print("SAVED")
        } catch {
            // error
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to loop through results to get the index. You can try this.

```
var results = context.fetch(request)
if let index = results.index(where: { (result) -> Bool in 
                                        result.value(forKey: "source") == title
                                     })
  {
        results.remove(at: index)
  }
```

Comment: I tried adding your code and I got the following error on the `result.value(forKey: "source") == title` line. Error: `Value of type 'any' has no member 'value'` Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

A likely cause of `Cannot invoke index with an argument list of type '(of: X)`

is because the type `X` does not conform to `Equatable`

Answer (score 1):

> In `arr.index(of: <Element>)`, Element should conform to `Equatable`, and type `X` does not conform to `Equatable`:
>
> For an array of `[X]`, use `arr.index(where:)`

---

### [image]

**Update your code as:**

```
if let index = results.index(where: { $0 as? String == title }) {
   print(index)
}
```